# WindowsService.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: .net, windows-services, windows-xp

My service sometimes fails. It's not bad, and on windows 7 and windows server 2003, service restarts. But on windows XP I see message "WindowsService.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." I added my service to the list of applications that are to be excluded from error reporting. It did not help - message showing without "Send report" and "Don't send". 
The main problem in the fact that there is not unhandled exeption in my service. There is error in one dll (with unmanaged cod) and I can't correct it.
How can I set my service so, that is work without this massages?
Added:
All my code in a try / catch block. Event log is "Faulting application WindowsService.exe, version 1.0.0.0, faulting module .dll, fault address 0x00010616."

Comment: I hope your program has a better name than "WindowsService.exe" and that this is only an example name you chose for SO.

Comment: Yah! I found it! **SetLastError** function in **kernel32.dll** hides the error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to catch this exception is a Bad Idea, an access violation is quite a nasty one.  Subscribe to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event in your Main() method.  In your event handler call Environment.Exit(1).  This is *not* guaranteed to run, the unmanaged code might have started its own thread.  The garlic cross you need for that one is SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(), you should write this in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the problematic code in a `try` / `catch` block and log the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. But there is not unhandled exeption in my service.  There is error in one dll (with unmanaged cod) and I can't correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the problematic code in a try/catch block, from here you can then use the exception data and write it to a log which could be used for error reporting or debugging.

I'm assuming you're developing in C#:

[try/catch - C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb:

- All direct methods in windows service must be wrapped in a try catch block
- All Service's OnStart must do a very minimum thing of starting a timer/looper/polling worker.

Comment: Ok, where can I read about the detailed restrictions in the method OnStart?

Comment: I run a thread in in OnStart method. But I can't find information about it on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx